# Is Using Event Handlers as "reusable code" bad practice?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

## The Situation

*This is a conceptual question and I will attempt to be as clear as I possibly can. Don't read the question if you have no interest in conceptual questions.*

Okay so there is some pre-written code that I am working on and in this code they reuse event handlers as some form of OOP.

An example of some event handler:

```
protected void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    //SOME LOGIC
}
```

An example of "reusing" the above event handler:

*Note: This is called at an arbitrary point in the Web App with the point of reusing the //SOME LOGIC part.*

```
{
    btnSomeButton_Click(null, null);
}
```

**Some points for the sake of clarity**

- The above method works.
- The event handler works in its normal sense.

## What I assume should be done

By my reasoning the correct way to do this would be to create a separate method and call this method when attempting to reuse the code. (Feel free to correct me)

```
protected void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    somefunction();
}
```

and to reuse the code:

```
{
    somefunction()
}
```

The method being something like this:

```
void somefunction()
{
    //SOME LOGIC
}
```

## The Question | My Problem

I want to be able to tell my superiors why I want to change this code. All they see is this code works, "great", but looking at this coding style hurts my eyes.

What is the conceptual reason behind not coding in the way the first example is coded? Or is this acceptable and should I just leave it?

Comment: What is the conceptual reason: symmetry and consistency (one handler forwards, the other doesn't). But it also means what appears to be change for one event handler impacts the other. Calling another method is an indicator of shared code. However: this is very much a subjective area.

Comment: I agree that btnSomeButton_Click(null, null) is a quick and dirty coding, even if I use it sometimes. But it is difficult to find strong argumentation to justify (small) reengeneering.

Comment: "Superiors" invariably have a very different point of view, a dev spending time on making stylistic changes instead of working on the sprint is forever low on their list of useful activities.  Just make the change when you have *another* reason to alter the source code file.

Comment: To those voting to close this question as opinion based, please properly read the guidelines for selecting that as a reason to close: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*  This question may well have *some degree of opinion based on expert experience* but they are based on *facts, references, or specific expertise.* So it should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your reasoning of putting the code into a separate function.
The main problem I had when dealing with these kinds of reuses is that one usually does **not expect** something that looks like a handler for a framework event to be **called by something else** than the framework.
The **parameters** in your example state a very important point: *Right now* they are not used but this can change in the future. The framework usually gives certain guarantees for the parameters, for example that they will never be `null`: When editing the code, one might say "why should I not trust the framework?" and omit any `null` checks. This will then fail for the non-framework code that simply passes `null`.
Another issue I often encountered is that handlers can get extended later with code that is not desirable or even harmful in the case of a "manual" call. A simple example that comes to mind would be logging something like "user clicked button", when in fact the user didn't.

I prefer to put each *action* that's performed in a framework handler into its own function, which has a clear name and can be called on its own.

Comment: Both answers are great, but you gave a practical example which is essentially what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers are loosely coupled, ie the code firing the event has no knowledge of the method its calling until the latter is registered.

If that method is then called from elsewhere in the code, by passing it in as an `Action<object, EventArgs>` and it's then called that way, the calling code still has no knowledge of the method until injected, so it's still loosely coupled.

Calling an event handler directly though tightly couples  the event handler to the calling code. If you want to change the event handler later, you could end up breaking that code and you'd have to check for all references to it (which can become spread throughout the code) first. Testing becomes more difficult too as tightly coupled code is inherently more difficult to separate into units and so the tests become more complex, require more mocking and are far more fragile.

Event handlers should be made private and should only be exposed to other parts of the code via "tell, don't ask" (eg by registering it against an event).

Comment: Well this makes sense. Deeply complicates testing and debugging. So I would be in the right to make the recommendation to remove the reusing of these eventhandlers?

Comment: I'd not recommend simply switching to the `somefunction()` option as you are still coupling. Instead you should (at least in the long term) being looking at using dependency injection and either passing `somefunction()` (or more likely its class) to other parts of the code that need to call it.

Comment: Having said that, if the `somefunction()` route sets your "superiors" on the path to understanding there's more to code than just it "working" and that quality is equally important, then I'd fully support it :)